# Redirect to youtube by clicking on youtube video

Tags: javascript

```
`https://viid.su/rfCYe`
```

the problem is on this page, well when people click on the embeded youtube video, I dont want the video to play there, but redirect people on youtube so they can interact, such as like or subscibe.

Comment: Check the youtube api and build not a youtube video but just link with video thumbnail and href to youtube

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the player to be usable, you can just put an image with a link on top of it.
Also there is the solution of using Youtubes Player API :
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements

I'm pretty sure you can catch the click of the user and redirect with javascript ( `window.location` or something like that )